# Can I detect when a language is detected for the first time using i18next-browser-languageDetector?

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next, i18next-browser-languagedetector

I have a react app that I have translated into several languages, and also contains some date formatting functionality. I would like to for example, allow the user to change between 12h and 24h time, however when switching to German, automatically change that option to 24h (as Germany typically doesn't use 12h time).

I still want this option to be able to be changed by the user, and I also don't want it to be reset to 24h every time the page reloads.

I'm using `i18next` and `i18next-browser-languageDetector` to detect the browser language, and currently I have an event bound to `i18next` for when the language is manually changed by the user, in order to set these default settings per language, and this works perfectly:

```js
i18n.on('languageChanged', lang => {
  // Language specific options
  if (lang === 'de') {
    store.setTimeFormat('24h');
  }
  if (lang === 'en') {
    store.setTimeFormat('12h');
  }
});
```

Now, the only problem is that this function is not triggered when first loading the app, i.e. when the browser detector first detects the user's language.

How can I determine when `i18next-browser-languageDetector` initially detects the language, that is, not loading from localstorage, but a query string of `lng=de` for example would trigger it, so that I can set these settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by first checking if a language had been saved in localstorage, adding this to the i18next options object, then I could check this later to set the defaults.

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';

// Check the localstorage before i18next can
const storedLang = localStorage.getItem('i18nextLng');

i18n
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(Backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    backend: {
      loadPath: '/i18n/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    },
    storedLang, // Add it here
  });

export default i18n;
```

Then in my component, I can put the following in the function:

```js
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { mySettingsStore } from 'stores';

const setDefaults = (lang, store) => {
  // Language specific options
  if (lang === 'de') {
    store.setTimeFormat('24h');
  }
  if (lang === 'en') {
    store.setTimeFormat('12h');
  }
  // etc...
};

const Component = () => {
  const store = mySettingsStore(); // zustand store
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();

  // If localstorage was empty: no language set
  if (!i18n.options.storedLang) {
    setDefaults(i18n.language, store);
    i18n.options.storedLang = i18n.language;
  }

  // Language changed manually
  i18n.on('languageChanged', lang => {
    setDefaults(lang, store);
  });

  return (...);
};

export default Component;
```

This method doesn't however update the options if a language is set via query string, e.g. `https://my.app?lng=de`, if a language is already set in the localstorage. This could be remedied by also checking the query string parameters in the same way, but it could quickly become cumbersome to maintain if more options are used, e.g. session storage, cookies, etc.

Answer (score 2):

For the first detected language, you may want to try the [onInitialized event](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#oninitialized).
Then check [i18next.language](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#language) or [i18next.languages](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#languages), depending on your needs.

edit: since v21.0.0 there is also [i18next.resolvedLanguage](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#resolvedlanguage)

Comment: The problem is that this event can't tell if a language has already been saved in the localstorage, session or cookie, etc. by the `i18next-browser-languagedetector` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much I have a problem in the first render access becouse i18n.language is "es-ES" or "en-EN" and save this on localstorage...
I solved it with a swtich case staments:

```
if (!i18n.options.storedLang) {
    switch(i18n.language){
       case "es-ES":
         setDefaults("es", store)
         i18n.options.storedLang = "es"
         //and this for other uses, for example vars to use in <ReactCountryFlag countryCode={"GB"} svg />
         break
      case: "en-EN":
         setDefault("en",store)
         i18n.options.storedLang = "es"
         //and this for other uses, for example vars to use in <ReactCountryFlag countryCode={"ES"} svg />
         break
      default: break
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you not use the i18next.resolvedLanguage value? https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#resolvedlanguage